# Replace the key value in a list with the relevant matching values from another list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to replace the key values in a dict inside a list(here only for the values inside Objectids) with the matching values from another list. Somehow i am only able to replace the 1st value but not iterating the whole list. Here the same key in the input.json will have multiple matching values from the finallist.json and all those values needs to be matched and added to the get the final expected output.

**Input.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "DNS_One",
        "objectIds": [
            "DNS_One",
            "DNS_One-HO",
            "NTP"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DNS_Two",
        "objectIds": [
            "NTP"
        ]
    }
]
```

**finallist.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "net_name": "DNS_One"
    },
    {
        "id": "789101112",
        "net_name": "DNS_One"
    },
    {
        "id": "131415161718",
        "net_name": "DNS_One-HO"
    },
    {
        "id": "23897845",
        "net_name": "NTP"
    },
    {
        "id": "9879879546",
        "net_name": "NTP"
    }
]
```

**Playbook**

```
- name: Id mapping
      vars: 
       objectid: >-
        {{ 
          finallist
          | selectattr('net_name', 'in', item.1)
          | map(attribute = 'id')
          | first
          | default([])
          }}
      set_fact:
        obj: >-
         {{
            obj | default([]) + 
            [item.0 | combine({'objectIds': [objectid]})]
         }}
      with_subelements:
           - "{{ input }}"
           - objectIds
      ignore_errors: yes
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "name": "DNS_One",
        "objectIds": [
            "123456","789101112"
            "131415161718",
            "23897845","9879879546"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DNS_Two",
        "objectIds": [
            "23897845","9879879546"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: There is a missing comma in the lists of the expected result. It's not clear what format of the lists you want. The answer gives you both nested and flatted lists.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka, Sorry, thats my bad. Expected is with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data and create the variables *finallist* and *input*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        finallist: "{{ lookup('file', 'finallist.json')|from_yaml }}"
    - set_fact:
        input: "{{ lookup('file', 'input.json')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
finallist:
  - id: '123456'
    net_name: DNS_One
  - id: '789101112'
    net_name: DNS_One
  - id: '131415161718'
    net_name: DNS_One-HO
  - id: '23897845'
    net_name: NTP
  - id: '9879879546'
    net_name: NTP
```

```yaml
input:
  - name: DNS_One
    objectIds:
    - DNS_One
    - DNS_One-HO
    - NTP
  - name: DNS_Two
    objectIds:
    - NTP
```

In *finallist*, group the items by *net_name* and convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        finaldict: "{{ finaldict|d({})|
                       combine({item.0: item.1|map(attribute='id')}) }}"
      loop: "{{ finallist|groupby('net_name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  finaldict:
    DNS_One:
    - '123456'
    - '789101112'
    DNS_One-HO:
    - '131415161718'
    NTP:
    - '23897845'
    - '9879879546'
```

Iterate *input* and substitute the IDs

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new: "{{ new|d([]) + [item|combine({'objectIds': _ids})] }}"
      loop: "{{ input }}"
      vars:
        _ids: "{{ item.objectIds|map('extract', finaldict)|list }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  new:
    - name: DNS_One
      objectIds:
      - ['123456', '789101112']
      - ['131415161718']
      - ['23897845', '9879879546']
    - name: DNS_Two
      objectIds:
      - ['23897845', '9879879546']
```

You can flatten the lists if you want to

```yaml
       _ids: "{{ item.objectIds|map('extract', finaldict)|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  new:
    - name: DNS_One
      objectIds: ['123456', '789101112', '131415161718', '23897845', '9879879546']
    - name: DNS_Two
      objectIds: ['23897845', '9879879546']
```